# Responsive html file tester

Tags: java, html, responsive-design, jsoup

I am building an application in Java which will take a HTML file as an input and as an output, it will display in console if the input HTML file is responsive or not.
I have decided to use Jsoup for this application development.
Right now, the basic logic that I am working with is the application will read the HTML file and look for a 'media query' block in it. If it finds it, it will give an output as 'Responsive HTML' else 'Not Responsive'.
Unfortunately I am not able to read the HTML file line by line. Can any one help me in doing so?
This is my code so far which is reading a small sample HTML file named 'x.html' stored in the class path and displaying its title.
Since there is a predefined method to extract title from html file using Jsoup, it was not difficult to do it. 
But I am facing trouble in searching for a string say "@media query" in the html file that is being loaded.

```
package dynamic_tester;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;  
public class tester {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {       
      Document htmlFile = null;
      {
       try {
        htmlFile = Jsoup.parse(new File("x.html"), "ISO-8859-1");
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       String title = htmlFile.title();
       System.out.println("Title = "+title);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search for a string in html file using Jsoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314463/search-for-a-string-in-html-file-using-jsoup)