# Search for a string in html file using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Can anyone help me with searching for a particular string in HTML file using Jsoup or any other method. There are inbuilt methods but they help in extracting title or script texts inside a specific tags and not string in general.
In this code I have used one such inbuilt method to extract title from the html page.
But I want to search a string instead.

```
package dynamic_tester;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;  
public class tester {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {       
Document htmlFile = null;
{
try {
    htmlFile = Jsoup.parse(new File("x.html"), "ISO-8859-1");

}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String title = htmlFile.title();
System.out.println("Title = "+title);
}
}
}
```

Comment: If you want to search String then why not just use String's `indexOf()` method ?

Comment: But I dont have a String or a text file to do such operation. I can do it on HTML files as well, because I was of the view what I cannot use indexOf() operation on html files.

Comment: You can use indexOf operation on HTML files. They are essentially plain text. Just read it in a String and search for whatever you need.

Comment: Thank you @11thdimension, I will give it a shot and come back here if I need any further help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample. It reads the HTML file as text String and then performs search on that String.

```
package com.example;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class SearchTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StringBuffer htmlStr = getStringFromFile("test.html", "ISO-8859-1");
        boolean isPresent = htmlStr.indexOf("hello") != -1;

        System.out.println("is Present ? : " + isPresent);
    }

    private static StringBuffer getStringFromFile(String fileName, String charSetOfFile) {
        StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10240]; //10K buffer;
            int readLen = -1;

            while( (readLen = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                strBuffer.append( new String(buffer, 0, readLen, Charset.forName(charSetOfFile)));
            }

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        }

        return strBuffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @11thdimension. Although going by your previous comment, I just replaced the text file with HTML file and it working fine. But thanks for the code as well. For now, I am using my own code.